# T-SQL, SQL Server Compact Edition, Alias For SELECT

Tags: t-sql, select, sql-server-ce, alias

How can I optimize my SQL code ?

I want to add alias.

I am using SQL Server Compact Edition.

( ... ) is a `SELECT` query

```
SELECT
    *
FROM ( ... )
WHERE
    id IN
    (
        SELECT
            id
        FROM ( ... )
        GROUP BY
            id
        HAVING
            COUNT( * ) > 1
    )
```

Comment: are both queries in (...) same?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use that query only once. You can create a CTE of that query and then write the query as follows:

```
with cte
As
(....)
Select * 
    from cte 
    where id in 
        (select id from cte 
            group by id 
            having count(*) > 1)
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

this is another option:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY id) ids FROM (...)) x
WHERE ids>1
```